# newline statment does not works in Log4Net under Vista Guest account

Tags: windows-vista, log4net, newline

I'm using Log4Net (1.2.10.0) for logging in my application. 
It's working fine - till I run it on Vista SP2 under Guest user. The log file does not contains a newline characters - all log is a single line.
This is not happen when I run the application as regular or admin user.
Only in case of built-in guest account.

Any ideas?

The configuration is as following:

```
<appender name="clientRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\users\public\client.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger [%type{1}] [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Thank

Comment: Does this happen on any other Vista account (admin, non-admin)? Does it happen on other Vista machines? Does it happen on any other machines you've got (Xp, Win 7, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following layout, which includes a newline in *code* and not in configuration. See if the problem still occurs.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout">
```

This won't "fix" anything, but it may help us narrow down the issue.